# How can I delete old records for SQLite in weekly?

Tags: sqlite, job-scheduling

I use a local database which is SQLite in my .net windows form application. The app will be run for 24 hours so it will never closed. So I need to remove old records in every Sunday in week. How can I do that? Should I write a batch file and create a task scheduler? Can we do this with batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a batch file to do so and set it up with the Task Scheduler, yes.

Something like this:

```
sqlite3 yourdb.db
sqlite> .read pathtoyourscript.sql
```

ref: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Personally I tend to find that a console application (especially with something like CommandLineParser) is a better way to go in terms of organization and ongoing maintenance, but you could do either way.